# How to make x axis label show up at the bottom not the top in Annotated Heatmap plotly python?

Tags: python, heatmap, plotly

I created a annotated heatmap in plotly python. The problem is that the default location for the x axis is at the top not the bottom of the graph. I have been searching the reference page and cannot figure out how to configure this. The default for a regular heatmap is at the bottom but the annotated heatmap version default is at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Plotly's `figurefactory` returns a `dict`ionary which you can modify. In this case you would set [`side`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-side) of your `xaxis` to `bottom`.

```
fig['layout']['xaxis']['side'] = 'bottom'
```

[image]

Example taken from [here](https://plot.ly/python/annotated_heatmap/#custom-text-and-x--y-labels).

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

z = [[.1, .3, .5],  
     [1.0, .8, .6],
     [.6, .4, .2]]

x = ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C']
y = ['Game Three', 'Game Two', 'Game One']

z_text = [['Win', 'Lose', 'Win'],  
          ['Lose', 'Lose', 'Win'],
          ['Win', 'Win', 'Lose']]

fig = plotly.figure_factory.create_annotated_heatmap(z, 
                                                     x=x, 
                                                     y=y, 
                                                     annotation_text=z_text, 
                                                     colorscale='Viridis')
fig['layout']['xaxis']['side'] = 'bottom'
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```