# x axis label location in annotated heatmap with plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

I get an plotting issue when trying to draw annotated heatmap with python plotly:

My code is like:

```
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(zlist, x=xlist, y=ylist, colorscale='Viridis')
fig['layout'].update(height=1500, width=1500, title='')
plt.plot(fig, filename='annotated_heatmap_text')
```

Here i have x axis label on the top. Is it possible to move it down to bottom? Thanks a lot! (i try to attach a plot but failed due to my low reputation...)

Answer (score 1):

Not using plotly, but I'm pretty sure this is already answered here:

[How to make x axis label show up at the bottom not the top in Annotated Heatmap plotly python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087866/how-to-make-x-axis-label-show-up-at-the-bottom-not-the-top-in-annotated-heatmap)

The line you are looking for is this (presumably, haven't tested):

```
fig['layout']['xaxis']['side'] = 'bottom'
```